# Some Character read only in textbox using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Textbox

```
<input id="txtbo" type="text" value="CAN'T TOUCH THIS!" size="50" />
```

jQuery or Javascript Code:

```
var readOnlyLength = $('#txtbo').val().length;

$('#txtbo').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
        && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
        || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

i am using this code but event was not fire. than i am using second code that is defined bellow:

```
function makeInitialTextReadOnly(input) {
    var readOnlyLength = input.value.length;
    field.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var which = event.which;
        if (((which == 8) && (input.selectionStart <= readOnlyLength))
                || ((which == 46) && (input.selectionStart < readOnlyLength))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    field.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        var which = event.which;
        if ((event.which != 0) && (input.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}

makeInitialTextReadOnly(document.getElementById('field'));
```

it is also doesn't work. if have you any solution or any new idea than give me plzz.

Comment: Your id is `txtbo` and in your jquery you search `field`, only typo?

Comment: Yes, I was changed name but it isn't work..

Comment: If it's the beginning of an input, why don't you use 2 inputs and style them so they appear as one?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make input read only then you can use `disabled` attribute in input field.Or you may use div to display instead input.

Comment: title of question is `Some Character read only` not `text box read only` so you can't use `disabled` attribute.